# Problem renaming files with python, some characters refuse to change.(Problem changing encoding, probably)

Tags: python, encoding, rename, filenames

I've searched around, but while I've seen some issues similar to mine, I haven't managed to get enough information to solve my problem...

A colleague of mine's working on a Wordpress site, and they're having problems with viewing some images(they wouldn't show on the slide show).
The images that were not showing were the ones that had their names in Greek, so their guess was that it was a naming problem.
So I thought I'd help by writing a script to mass-rename said images form Greek to Greeklish(a form of greek that uses latin characters and was popular among greeks in the earlier days of the internet - for those not familiar with the term).

I've tested the script with all kinds of greek characters it worked perfectly, including the kinds of signs particular to the Greek language.

When I ran the script on the images that I wanted renamed though, some of the images showed an issue. They would rename some accented characters to french accented characters (like ά to à etc) but when I added these to the dictionary(I used a dictionary to parse the names and replace greek letters) they refused to change.

For example on this filename "palaiá-póli-4-768x480" I ran the script twice: the first one converted it from "Παλαιά-Πόλη-4-768x156" to the name above and the second run did nothing, even after adding "á":"a" and "ó":"o" to the character map(which was not there before as ó and á are not greek characters.)

My script is as follows:

```
import os


char_migrate = {
    "ς": 's',
    'ε': 'e', 'ρ': 'r', "τ": "t", "υ": "y", "θ": "th", "ι": "i", "ο": "o", "π": "p", "α": "a",
    "σ": "s", "δ": "d", "φ": "f", "γ": "g", "η": "i", "ξ": "x", "κ": "k", "λ": "l",
    "ζ": "z", "χ": "x", "ψ": "ps", "ω": "o", "β": "v", "ν": "n", "μ": "m",
    "Ε": "e", "Ρ": "r", "Τ": "t", "Υ": "y", "Θ": "th", "Ι": "i", "Ο": "o", "Π": "p", "Α": "a",
    "Σ": "s", "Δ": "d", "Φ": "f", "Γ": "g", "Η": "i", "Ξ": "x", "Κ": "k",
    "Λ": "l", "Ζ": "z", "Χ": "x", "Ψ": "ps", "Ω": "o", "Β": "v", "Ν": "n", "Μ": "m",
    "Έ": "e", "Ά": "a", "Ύ": "y", "Ί": "i", "Ό": "o", "Ή": "i", "Ώ": "o",
    "έ": "e", "ά": "a", "ύ": "y", "ί": "i", "ό": "ο", "ή": "i", "ώ": "o",
    "ϋ": "i", "ϊ": "i", "ΐ": "i", "ΰ": "i",
    "Ϊ": "i", "Ϋ": "i"
}


os.chdir('C:/Users/alift/Desktop/RenameTestFolder')
for f in os.listdir():
    name = f
    new_name = ""
    for l in name:
        if l in char_migrate:
            b = char_migrate[l]
            new_name += b
        else:
            new_name += l
    os.rename(f, new_name)
```

What I've tried so far is trying to add .encode(encoding="xxx") on new_name inside os.rename, trying Unicode, UTF-8 and Ansi(only UTF-8 made my script run without errors, but I read that that's the default encoding that python uses, and I didn't get any results).

In the end, my problem must probably be just that I need to batch-change the encoding instead of batch change the names as I did, but I don't know how to do that.

Any tips or insight?
Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beware accented characters in unicode can be a nightmare, because most of them exist in 2 different form: composed and decomposed. For example the latin `à` is LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH GRAVE U+00E0. But it can be `'\u0061\u0300'`, LATIN SMALL LETTER A followed with COMBINING GRAVE ACCENT. The `unicodedata` module provides the `normalize` function to convert to any of those forms. The only way to distinguish them is to dump their hexa codes, but they are not equal per Python string equality operator.

So when things go wrong and accented characters are involved:

1. dump the hexadecimal codes to better understand what happens under the hood
2. use a normalized form to limit the disambiguation problem

   ```
   >>> print hex(ord(normalize('NKFC', '\u0061\u0300')))
   0x6e
   ```

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot! 
I've added combining characters that I found here: 
http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0300.pdf to the character map and mapped them to an empty string and it worked as a charm! :)

Answer (score 0):

i think it can be a windows thing because i run your script under linux/ python 3 and it works flawlessly.

```
Input file:
Παλαιά-Πόλη-4-768x156.txt
Output file:
palaia-pοli-4-768x156.txt
```

Comment: Hmmmm, I don't think it can really be copied. When I copy the name and name a file of my own it works fine. It's when I use the original files that I'm getting the problem. I'll try to open the same file on my linux machine though and see how it works as I haven't tried it there!